# How to compare dates in Carbon on Laravel Blade View?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I wish to compare two dates - `$dateX` (datetime in past) with `$currentDatetime` (current datetime). For instance: check if `$dateX` was 7 days ago or not. All should happen in Laravel Blade Engine view by using Carbon.

Can you give some example? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? For example if $dateX is 7 days ago, what should happen then, what do you want to show?

Comment: @lagbox examples from doc was unclear, I wish to see another approach, that is all.

Comment: @lewis4u Then I want to display information that the event took place 7 days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This think can be achieved easily with Carbon, so i'm supposing that both `$dateX` and `$currentDateTime` are `Carbon` instances, accordingly if you wanna check time diff in days simply use `diffInDays`

for example

```
if( $currentDateTime->diffInDays( $dateX ) > 7 ){
    // do sonething here
}
```

in the end i really wanna say that carbon docs are very clear and easy to read

Comment: In fact,if i want to use it in blade it should look like: {{ Carbon\Carbon::today()->diffInDays(Carbon\Carbon::parse($dateX)) }}

Answer (score 1):

First get these date times into carbon instances.

```
@if ($dateX->diffInDays($currentDateTime, false) == 7)
    ...
@endif
```

[Carbon Docs - Difference](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the date is earlier than a week ago, you could do this:

```
@if ($dateX < now()->subWeek())
```

The `diffInDays()` will work too, but only if all `$dateX` days are in the past and always will be. The code above is more explicit. Also, what if you'll need to change the logic?

Comment: `diffInDays` take a second argument, for absolute, set it to false and it will return a negative number in that case, which would not equal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this with `diff`. Also check if a date is set before the other.

```
$date1 = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2017, 10, 10);
$date2 = \Carbon\Carbon::create(2017, 10, 20);

$difference = $date1->diff($date2)->days;
$before = $date1 < $date2;

if (before && $difference < 7) {
    //Date 1 more than 7 days before date 2            
}
```